# How to exclude *.d.ts file for TypeScript compiler?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I use a npm module web3@1.0.0-beta.24 which has some mistakes in its index.d.ts file.

I want to ignore this file (node_modules/web3/index.d.ts) for TS compiler and I want to use my own types file.

But tsc still use this wrong file and can't compile my project.

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true
  },

  "exclude": ["node_modules/web3/index.d.ts"]
}
```

If I manually remove `node_modules/web3/index.d.ts`, tsc compiles my project.

How to exclude this file for tsc?

I've created a repo with minimum code to reproduce this problem:
https://github.com/serge-nikitin/q1

Comment: did you try a wildcard?

Comment: "exclude": ["node_modules/web3/*.d.ts"]
Such wildcard doesn't work too

Answer (score 41):

Try add this options to tsconfig.json to ignore lib declaration files checking while compiling.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
}
```

Comment: For me with TypeScript v3.9.9 and Win10, this does not work. I have still d.ts files in my list of files during build process

Comment: No, this is not skip generating d.ts files but skip types checking for d.ts files.

Comment: No, I never solved it. But I also did not investigate much more